# apache archiva doesn't load plugin from central repo

Tags: java, maven, archiva

I want to use Apache Archiva like a company repo and mirror of the central maven repo(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2). 
But archiva can't download jar from central repo, when I call archiva's server.
Somebody knowns how to fix it?
Result of compile my project is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://localhost:8080/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh/1.0-beta-7/wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-7.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh:jar:1.0-beta-7 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://localhost:8080/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh/1.0-beta-7/wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-7.jar
Downloading: http://localhost:8080/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   The project MyProject:2.05:1.0 (d:\Work\test_maven\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh:1.0-beta-7 or one of its dependencies 
could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh:jar:1.0-beta-7,
org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh:jar:1.0-beta-7 
in internal (http://localhost:8080/) -> [Help2]
```

I use default archiva settings for repositories and proxyConnectors (have connector from internal to central repo. I don't use a proxy for Internet).
Central repo "remote check" is correct.
My maven settings.xml:

```
<mirror>
      <id>internal</id>      
      <name>Archiva Internal Repository</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>Maven Default Project</name>
  <groupId>MyProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>2.05</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>    
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>own</groupId>
        <artifactId>imapown</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>  
  <build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
        </extension>        
    </extensions>       
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>    
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>  
  </build>    
</project>
```

Version jdk: 1.6.0_45, maven: 3.2.5, archiva: 2.2.1